# Is there a way to figure out what the widest element inside another element is?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have the following issue: I'm working on an old website which uses a table layout. It's a huge, messy table with up to a hundred elements inside it. I'm not posting the code deliberately - it's enormous and I doubt anyone would have the patience or the will to go through it.

The problem I'm facing is the following: something is stretching the table, making it wider than it's supposed to be. I've tried going through the whole code to figure out what's going on, but no luck. I tried setting the width of the table to a fixed value, but no result.

So, my question is, is there a way to figure out (maybe using Javascript/jQuery) what the widest element in the table is? That would probably help me figure out what's stretching it, because going through this stuff line by line is going to take hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('*').each(function() {
       var oldWidth = $('body').data('width');
       if(oldWidth != 'undefined' && $(this).width() > oldWidth)
          $('body').data('width', $(this).width()); 
    });
});
```

Haven't tested. Hope it will help!